# Restore Firebase Collection Deleted

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I accidentally deleted a collection from my project on firebase database. 
Is it be possible to restore it? Firebase has a rollback option?

Comment: The Realtime database has the option to enable backup, if you're using the Blaze plan. Firestore has no backup options that I know of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to restore neither a document nor a collection at the moment.
If you are storing potential data, which you can't afford to lose, A good practice would be to create another project under the same account and frequently export the entire database to that project. (Maybe once a week or 15 days, depending on the traffic of your application.)
For databases containing large amounts of data, this might lead to almost double the firestore charges, but at least your data will be safe.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, but no. Once you delete something in the database, its gone. 
Only Firebase hosting has a rollback option.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your database collection name in your code.
2. make your new build.
3. run firebase deploy.

It worked for me.